# Windows Explorer pinned icons break when installing developer tools

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7, windows-explorer

I'm having a very strange problem that I've noticed whenever I install anything that involves Visual Studio.  I haven't noticed it with non-VS related installations.  For example, I'm currently installing the latest Azure SDK.  As soon as the installation starts, the Windows Explorer pinned icon on the task bar breaks.  When I click it I get the "Can't open this item" dialog.

[image: can't open this item dialog]

Also, two of the pinned icons on the start menu break as well.  One is the icon to Remote Desktop Connection.  It still works, just the icon is broken.  The other is the icon for Internet Information Services Manager.  It stops working completely, not even giving me a "Can't open this item" dialog.

[image: broken start menu icons]

When I restart the computer the icons start working again.  This is getting rather tiresome.  Sometimes even updating a Visual Studio Extension does this. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I get something very similar.  I keep things like Explorer, Notepad, Calculator & Paint pinned to the TaskBar and it seems like unrelated installs just wallop these icons.  I just downloaded a Microsoft Security Essentials update and they broke again.  I noticed to my surprise that my Remote Desktop Connection icon I had pinned to the Start Menu just died.  Time for another reboot, grr.

Comment: Update. Instead of rebooting I followed this other post, deleting the icon cache and stop/starting the Explorer Process:
http://superuser.com/questions/173442/how-to-fix-broken-taskbar-icons-in-windows-7

I also found another blog entry by someone with similar issue who uses SSD C drive like I do:
http://htks.kylemilnes.com/2012/04/windows-7-taskbar-pinned-items-stop.html

I noticed the shortcuts I have trouble with use %windir% in the target path.  I'm going to replace with C:\Windows to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Since posting this I've been issued a new PC running Windows 8.1 and this issue hasn't reared it's head. I never did find a solution on the old Win7 machine. If I start having the problem on this computer I'll try hard coding that path to the Windows folder on the offending icons.